# Find degrees (0-360º) of point on a circle

Tags: svg, raphael, trigonometry

I'm working on a small webapp in which I need to rotate shapes. I
would like to achieve this by grabbing a point on a circle and
dragging it around to rotate the image.

Here's a quick illustration to help explain things:

[image: two points on circle, i'm looking to find the degrees of p1]

My main circle can be dragged anywhere on the canvas. I know it's
radius (r) and where 12 o'clock (p0) will always be (cx, cy - r). What
I need to know is what degree p1 will be (0-360º) so I can rotate the
contents of the main circle accordingly with Raphael.rotate().

I've run through a bunch of different JavaScript formulations to find this ([example](https://beradrian.wordpress.com/2009/03/23/calculating-the-angle-between-two-points-on-a-circle/)), but none seem to give me values between 0-360 and my basic math skills
are woefully deficient.

The [Color Picker demo](http://raphaeljs.com/picker/) (sliding the cursor along the ring on the right) has the behavior I want, but even after poring over the source code I can't seem to replicate it accurately.

Anything to point me in the correct direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
// Angle between the center of the circle and p1,
// measured in degrees counter-clockwise from the positive X axis (horizontal)
( Math.atan2(p1.y-cy,p1.x-cx) * 180/Math.PI + 360 ) % 360
```

The angle between the center of the circle and p0 will always be +90°. See [`Math.atan2`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2) for more details.